# Auto Complete in all the rows in the table

Tags: php, javascript, html, autocomplete

I am able to get the autocomplete list of the value in the first row of the table , but it is not populating in the next row. I want to populate autocomplete to populate in all the rows which is created by the while loop.. any help suggestion is highly appreciated.

I thought of using creating a function (onkeyup) to call autocomplete and embedded in my input field to make it work on all the rows.

I understand autocomplete is bound to the input id of the element and it is changing for the next row generated after first row,

how to handle this situation?

```
function getPath($id)
{
    echo "<table border='1px' width=650>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th width=120>Designation</th>";
    echo "</tr>";     
    echo "<br>";
    $sql1 = mysql_query("select * from t_path where f__id=$id");

    while($res  = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width=120><input type='text' name='change_desig' id = 'Designation' value='".$res['f_designation']."' onblur=updateDesigninDb(this.value,'".$res['f_start_dt']."',".$id.")></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
}



getPath($id);

?>

<!--Script to update data in DB ----------------------------------->
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function updateDesigninDb(designation)
  {
    var baseurl = "/updateDB.php";
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: baseurl,
        data: "designation="+designation                                            
        ,
        success: function(userDetails){

        }
          });


       }
    </script>

   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>

       var designation=[
        <?php
         $load = mysql_query("select f_designation from t_designation_master;");
         while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($load))
         {

           echo "'".$arr[0]."',";
         }
        ?>

     ].sort();

          AutoComplete_Create('Designation',designation);
              </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a common class on all the inputs instead of the same id.

something like:

```
echo "<td width=120><input type='text' class='autocomplete_input' value='".$res['f_designation']."' onblur=updateDesigninDb(this.value,'".$res['f_start_dt']."',".$id.")></td>";
```

If you need id on each input, I'd suggest to add a name + autoincremental number as a id.

If you are using Jquery you can apply autocomplete to all of them like this:

```
$(".autocomplete_input").autocomplete({source: url}); //url of the script that returns all the autocomplete values.
```

Comment: thnx ..it worked like charm..i switched to jquery and added class..and it's working.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe because all of your inputs in while loop have same id ="Designation"... There can only be one element with a specific id, they have to be unique. Maybe add an index $i =0 at beginning of while loop, increment it $i++ at end of loop and change id ="Designation".$ i... Or add your autocomplete by a classname?